# keosd doesn't pick up wallet-dir flag with bind mount (docker-compose)

Tags: cleos

After moving to 1.0.1 image keosd started ignoring my bind mount, can't figure out why.

My alias for cleos:

```
alias cleos='docker-compose exec keosd /opt/eosio/bin/cleos -u http://nodeosd:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8888'
```

When I perform any commands with **cleos** over wallet, it tries to get the wallet file from this place:

```
"/root/eosio-wallet/./default.wallet"
```

But it's supposed to operate in this directory:

```
/Users/me/Projects/block-producer-eos/keosd
```

Software versions:

```
OS: Mac OS 10.13.4
Docker: 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312)
Compose: 1.21.1
```

Here's my docker-compose.yaml :

```
        version: "3"

services:
  nodeosd:
    image: eosio/eos:v1.0.1
    command: /opt/eosio/bin/nodeosd.sh --data-dir /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir -e
    hostname: nodeosd
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
      - 9876:9876
    expose:
      - "8888"
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/Projects/block-producer-eos/nodeosd:/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir

  keosd:
    image: eosio/eos:v1.0.1
    command: /opt/eosio/bin/keosd --wallet-dir /opt/eosio/bin/data-dir --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8900
    hostname: keosd
    links:
      - nodeosd
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/Projects/block-producer-eos/keosd:/opt/eosio/bin/data-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the alias for cleos, didn't update wallet-url port:

```
alias cleos='docker-compose exec keosd /opt/eosio/bin/cleos -u http://nodeosd:8888 --wallet-url http://localhost:8900'
```